# How can ElasticSearch node join cluster at runtime?

Tags: elasticsearch, autodiscovery

Assume there are 3 running nodes launched with `multicast=false` and `unicast=true`, but no unicast nodes are given when starting. After they all get up, they are not aware of each other.

Is there a way to tell each one IP address of the other two so they can do discovery at runtime and join to same cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add the `ip` addresses of all the other nodes in the cluster to the

`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` property,

in the `elasticsearch.yml` file in the config folder.

Say you have three nodes, in each node, add the address of the other two nodes as below:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xx.xx.xxx.xx","yy.yy.yy.yy"]
```

Comment: Can you try updating the parameter in the node setting via the _cluster API and refreshing it dynamically.